# TreeMap sorting for a foreach, by keys

Tags: java, treemap

I would like some advice from the community about some code I wrote.  I have ...

```
TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,String>> tableError;
```

... and I have this `toString()` method:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    for( Integer line : this.tableError.keySet()){
        for(Integer pos : this.tableError.get(line).keySet()){
            s.append("line: "+line);
            s.append(":"+pos);
            s.append("\t"+this.tableError.get(line).get(pos));
            s.append("\n");
        }
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

I know that `TreeMap`s are algorithmically sorted by their keys.  I want know whether the `String`s obtained via that `toString()` method will always be sorted by my pos variable too?

My confusion arises in part because the javadocs for `keySet()` say that it returns a `Set`, but that doesn't explicitly promise that the key set is sorted. At least, I didn't see any such guarantee.

Comment: A `SortedMap`s [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#keySet--) will always be sorted, as by contract it is backed by the original `Map`. See the linked documentation.

Comment: lol, I sincerely don't know ... I'm speechless right now xD
How in the bloody hell i didn't see that : `The set's iterator returns the keys in ascending order.` Thank you !! @biziclop

Comment: You're welcome, and don't worry, it happens to everybody.

Comment: You should look into `.entrySet()` for code like this. In this particular case, not using it adds a log(m)log(n) factor (if the child maps all have m elements) to the runtime.